# How to obtain a kernel timestamp for an interrupt?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have an event from the realtime world, which generates an interrupt.  I need to register this event to one of the Linux kernel timescales, like CLOCK_MONOTONIC or CLOCK_REALTIME, with the goal of establishing when the event occurred in real calendar time.  What is the currently recommended way to do this?  My google search found some patches submitted back in 2011 to support it, but the interrupt-handling code has been heavily revised since then and I don't see a reference to timestamps anymore.

For my intended application the accuracy requirements are low (1 ms).  Still, I would like to know how to do this properly.  I should think it's possible to get into the microsecond range, if one can exclude the possibility of higher-priority interrupts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only low precision, you could get away with reading `jiffies`.
However, if `CONFIG_HZ` is less than 1000, you will not even get 1 ms resolution.

For a high-resolution timestamp, see how [firewire-cdev.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/firewire/core-cdev.c#n1216) does it:

```c
    case CLOCK_REALTIME:      getnstimeofday(&ts);  break;
    case CLOCK_MONOTONIC:     ktime_get_ts(&ts);    break;
    case CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW: getrawmonotonic(&ts); break;
```

Comment: Looks like I've got some reading to do.  Since asking the original question I also remembered the "PPS" driver used to hook up GPS time signals.  I'm curious if it uses one of these calls internally.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your needs right - you may use getnstimeofday() function for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the high precision monotonic clock value (which is usually a good idea) you should look at `ktime_get_ts()` function (defined in `linux/ktime.h`). `getnstimeofday()` suggested in the other answer returns the "wall" time which may actually appear to go backward on occassion, resulting in unexpected behavior for some applications.